# Why value of parameter not increased as passed address of that variable?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I have below program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fun1(int *getValue)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        *getValue++;
}

void fun2(int *getValue)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        *getValue=+1;
}

void main()
{
    int getValue=0,getValu2=0;
    fun1(&getValue);    
    fun2(&getValu2);
    printf("getValue :%d and getValu2 : %d\n", getValue, getValu2);
}
```

And the o/p of above program is

```
getValue :0 and getValu2 : 1
```

Now i am expecting value in both case should be `4` as i have passed variable's address in function?
Is my understanding wrong and is this behaviour correct? If yes then can any one explain it? Also what modification i needed to get correct value?

Comment: `*getValue++;` --> `++*getValue;`, `*getValue=+1;` --> `*getValue+=1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case you increase the address of the pointer (not the value of the passed variable):

Change to:

```
(*getValue)++;
```

In the second case you always assign `+1`

Change to

```
*getValue+=1;
```

Now it should be 4 and 4

Comment: You are welcome ;) Take a look to this table [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1):

[1] The output which you see is correct.

[2] The behavior which you see is because `*getValue++;` is same as `*(getValue++);` That is precedence of `operator++` is greater than `dereference operator *`. Therefore, as per precedence `getValue` gets incremented first and therefore no longer points to `int main::getValue` and hence `main::getValue` doesn't get incremented as intended.

[3] To get the intended behavior use `(*getValue)++`.

[4] Also, there is typing mistake or incorrect use of `operator +=` for incrementing value in `*getValue=+1;`. Correct way would be `*getValue += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    *getValue++;
```

Increases your pointer not the value in it and afterwards you dereference it. I THINK that this UB but I am not sure.

Try `(*getValue)++;` this will dereference the pointer first, then increase the value.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    *getValue=+1;
```

always sets the value to `+1` you want `*getValue+=1;`